# Events in Spring Boot

Tags: events, asynchronous, spring-boot

Is it possible to use events in Spring Boot? I need to execute one method but without waiting for return. I'm trying to use this:

```java
public class GerarSeloEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private TbPedido pedido;
    private Integer cdCartorio;

    public GerarSeloEvent(Object source, TbPedido pedido, Integer cdCartorio) {
        super(source);
        this.pedido = pedido;
        this.cdCartorio = cdCartorio;
    }

    public TbPedido getPedido() {
        return pedido;
    }

    public Integer getCdCartorio() {
        return cdCartorio;
    }
}

@Component
public class GerarSeloListener implements ApplicationListener<GerarSeloEvent> {
    @Autowired
    SeloService seloService;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(GerarSeloEvent event) {
        seloService.gerarSelos(event.getPedido(), event.getCdCartorio());
    }
}
```

and my call

```
GerarSeloEvent gerarSelos = new GerarSeloEvent(this, pedido, cdCartorio);
EnviarEmailPedidoEvent enviarEmail = new EnviarEmailPedidoEvent(this, pedido);
publisher.publishEvent(gerarSelos);
```

But my code waits to return anything to my front-end. I need one async event.

Comment: Not sure about how you structured your code as ideally it should work asynchronously but still in order to do anything in async mode "Threading" is the most common available option. Try it.

Comment: Springs application events are by default synchronized, you can configure it otherwise. One way is to simply put `@ASync` on the `onApplicationEvent` of your listener to have it async (or your service method). Else don't use events and simply create an async service method you are going to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Component
public class GerarSeloListener {

    private final SeloService seloService;

    @Autowired
    public GerarSeloListener(SeloService seloService) { ... }

    @EventListener
    @Async
    public void handleGerarSeloEvent(GerarSeloEvent event event) {
        ....
    }
```

You need to add `@EnableAsync` on one of your configuration (the best place is your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class). But as Martin already said you don't need event if you want to process a method asynchronously: only add `@Async` and invoke it the usual way.

You may want [to read the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support)